# Loss of TransE gets plateau at the margin value with BigDL library

Tags: scala, optimization, embedding, knowledge-graph, bigdl

I have been trying to use optimizer(SGD, Adagrad) from BigDL library on TransE with scala. My current implementation works with mini batch in sequential way. I followed this [example](https://bigdl-project.github.io/0.10.0/#APIGuide/Optimizers/Optim-Methods/#adagrad) to optimize the embeddings(as Tensors) without creating a layered model.My code is somewhat similar to this [example](https://github.com/SANSA-Stack/SANSA-ML/blob/develop/sansa-ml-spark/src/main/scala/net/sansa_stack/ml/spark/kge/linkprediction/models/TransE.scala). My current problem is, with some parameters my losses gets at a plateau point (the value of margin) no matter how many epochs I run. With this, my hit@10 in testing is not that good. Can someone give any idea why losses get at a plateaued point and if this generates bad testing results? 
P.S. I have checked my loss calculation and it is fine. The only place I have control over my implementation is the optimizer.

Thanks in advance.